# Show admob Interstitial Ad on Subview

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

I have used Admob Interstitial ad in my application and it get rejected in AppStore.

Reason was.

"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 8.2 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

Specifically the interstitial video ads were unable to be closed during review."

I didn't get video ad while testing on my Device.

Is there any way i solve this issue or how i can add this ad in SubView?

Comment: Are you able to recreate the issue on your device? The AdMob Framework handles the many different types of video ads it shows quite well in my experience. It may have just been a rare occurrence.

Comment: No, i am getting only test Image Interstitial ad on my device.

Comment: You should be able to receive live ads on your device. Don't use your testid when requesting the ad.